# Laravel - moving values from one column to another

Tags: php, laravel

My problem is as follows - in the database I have a Products table with a size column. However, I have now created two new columns x_size and y_size and I wanted to move the values from the size column to these 2 columns. I don't want to change everything manually because there are over 1,000 records in this table.

I have no idea how to go about it, I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Can you share more details about your setup, the db structure and such?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: for example, in the database I have a record, where the size column is 100x200, now I want to transfer the value 100 to the new x_size column and the value 200 to the y_size column, and so for each of the records in this table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy one column value to another column in MySQL perform below query.

```
UPDATE products SET x_size = SUBSTRING_INDEX(size,'x',+1)
UPDATE products SET y_size = SUBSTRING_INDEX(size,'x',-1)
```

Comment: Thanks but for example, in the database I have a record, where the size column is 100x200, now I want to transfer the value 100 to the new x_size column and the value 200 to the y_size column, and so for each of the records in this table

Comment: @PatrykPrzybylski Yes I have read an example. I will answer ..

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `products` SET `size` = CONCAT(x_size,' ', y_size);
```

Here I am using concat by white space that two-column, whatever you wish to use.

*Note:- Before take back up the particular table*